# Creating A Concatenated ID w/ Leading Zeroes Using Sequence in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, sequence, array-formulas

[image: Table]

I am very close here but due to my still novice understanding of Regular Expressions, I am not getting exactly the results I want.

In B1 sits a variable used to create a sequence.

The desired output is

> Team01,Team02,Team03,Team04,Team05,Team06,Team07,Team08,Team09,Team10,Team11,Team12

The data in that table is generated by this formula in B3

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"TeamID";"Team"&SEQUENCE(SUBSTITUTE(B1,"\\10\\2","^[1-9]\d*(?:\.\d{1,2})?$"))})
```

I know that the formula isn't working because the RegEx isn't correct and maybe i need to be using other tools, but I'm still new to this and trying to piece together what needs to change.

Comment: you cant regex without regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(SEQUENCE(B1), "\T\e\a\m0#"))
```

or shorter:

```
=INDEX(TEXT(SEQUENCE(B1), "\T\e\a\m0#"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can also try the even shorter and "*easier to the eye*"

```
=ARRAYFORMULA("Team"&TEXT(SEQUENCE(B1), "0#"))
```

or even

```
=INDEX("Team"&TEXT(SEQUENCE(B1), "0#"))
```